# Docker for Windows Server 2016 requires update KB3176936

Tags: windows, docker, server, containers

I want to install Docker on a physical Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Evaluation (Version 14393). I tried following the instructions from [Quick Start Windows Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server) but installation fails:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxIIO.png)

The docker installer requires update KB3176936, which I installed then. Even after rebooting, the error message persists and I can't install docker.

I've enabled the Container feature and Hyper-V in Windows Feature Selection.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've could sucessfully setup docker on Windows 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to do a full Windows Update. I actually have a PR [to add this step to the docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/pull/390/files).

Run `sconfig`, then choose option `6` and then `A` and `A` to install all updates. This works for Server 2016 in no-desktop installs as well as with the UI.

Comment: Thank you :))))) That helped!!